# Tensorflow Object Detection API Installation Verification Issues: "No module named 'official.legacy'"

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api, modulenotfounderror

[image: error message]

I was installing the Object Detection API for a personal project, I did all the steps mentioned in the official documentation from installing the COCO API to installing the Object Detection API.
In the last step of the installation, while verifying the Tensorflow Object Detection API installation, I encountered the following issues
It says offical.legacy module not found, I installed tf-models-official, but that didn't work for me.
Can somebody please help me out??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the test file by following the solution [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10505#issuecomment-1656715690) on the TensorFlow GitHub:

> Go to this file "....conda\envs\tfCV\Lib\site-packages\official\vision\image_classification\augment.py" on your device and change line 31 to this:
> from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image as image_ops

The path for me was

C:\Users\{YOUR-USERNAME}\miniconda3\envs\{YOUR_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT}\Lib\site-packages\official\vision\image_classification\augment.py

Replacing

`from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing import image_preprocessing as image_ops`

with

`from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image as image_ops`